# Is there any opposite to mongoose `$in` operator?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Need to remove items, ids of which are **not** presented in the array I pass. Don't want to make extra queries so I've already spent an hour trying to find something similiar to that but found nothing yet. I know MongoDB API is huge and has a ton of agregation operators but 'tis too complicated to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

> Syntax: `{ field: { $nin: [ <value1>, <value2> ... <valueN> ]} }`
>
> [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) selects the documents where:
>
> - the `field` value is not in the specified `array` **or**
> - the `field` does not exist.